# Unescaping strings stored in a collection

Tags: c#

I have a collection of strings that have some escaped characters in them.  I need to unescape the collection of strings before i can use them. Unfortunately HttpUtility.HtmlDecode doesnt seem to work on a collection passed to the method below.  Strangely in a separate console app i created to test it does work.  Any ideas?

```cs
private void UpdateTaxonomyTerms(TaxonomywebserviceSoapClient taxWebService, string termStoreId, string termSetId, List<string> TermsList)
{
    string TermsXML = GetTermSet(taxWebService, termStoreId, termSetId);

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(TermsXML);

    for (int i = 0; i < TermsList.Count; i++) {
        string UnescapedTermToFind = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(TermsList[i].ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(UnescapedTermToFind);

        string TermGuid = FindTerm(xDoc, UnescapedTermToFind);
        TermsList[i] = string.Concat(UnescapedTermToFind, "|", TermGuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sample input? expected output? `GetTermSet`? `FindTerm`?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it by a one-liner such as

```
string result = string.Join("|",
        TermsList.Select (term => 
            FindTerm(xDoc, System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(term))));
```

But, it's merely syntactic sugar and frankly, your loop is probably just as easy to read.